# SML: syntax error: replacing FUN with VAL

Tags: syntax, syntax-error, ocaml, sml

I am trying to write a function in ml that works like a for loop (yes i know its not how the language is supposed to work). So here is my code so far:

```
fun for (f:int->unit) start_i:int end_i:int = 
let fun for2 (f:int->unit) start_i:int end_i:int i:int =
    if i=end_i - 1 then
        f i
    else
        (f i;
        for2 f start_i end_i (i + 1))
in
    for2 f start_i end_i start_i
end
```

But sml (and Ocaml too) is giving me this error:

```
test.ml:1.2-1.5 Error: syntax error: replacing  FUN with  VAL
test.ml:2.6-2.9 Error: syntax error: replacing  FUN with  VAL
```

So, there is something wrong with my function's signature. But I can't find what it is. Can you help me?

Thanks

Comment: Does not look like a "real" for loop to me. Rather a callNTimes function.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Not sure if this also compiles in ocaml (is f#) but a version of this where interactive is not complaining about is:

```
let rec for2 (body: int->unit) iStart iEnd =
    if iStart = iEnd then ()
    else
        body iStart;
        for2 body (iStart+1) iEnd
```

Comment: it throws the same syntax error, theres something wrong with `(body: int -> unit)`

Comment: Fired up my freebsd where I have ocaml running. There, the only change to make it compile was the extra semicolon after the body invocation.

Comment: thanks it worked now for sml i had to replace `let rec` with `fun` and add parentheseses to the last 2 statements

Answer (score 1):

Your type annotations are incorrect.  You need parens around all of the parameters.

```
fun for (f:int->unit) (start_i:int) (end_i:int) =
    let fun for2 (f:int->unit) (start_i:int) (end_i:int) (i:int) =
        if i=end_i - 1 then
            f i
        else
            (f i;
            for2 f start_i end_i (i + 1))
    in
        for2 f start_i end_i start_i
    end
```

Comment: yes, thanks, i just figured it out myself too. I'm still a beginner in ml, didn't know parentheses were essential